# Find the range of a linear map $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Given the matrix
>   $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 1 \\ 2 & -3 \\ 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix},$$
>   compute the range of
>   $$T\colon\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^4,\quad x\mapsto Ax.$$

I'm not sure how to proceed. Do you take the transpose of $A$ which equals the coordinates given by $(x,y)$ in $R^4$ and then RREF to determine the vector bases and that computes the range?

Comment: no need for RREF or transpose for this; where does $T$ map $(1,0)$?  where does $T$ map $(0,1)$?  where does $T$ map a linear combination of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$?  any $x\in\Bbb R^2$ is a linear combination of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$

Comment: I'm looking for the range in R^4 not R^2

Comment: Yes, $T$ maps $(1,0)$ [and $(0,1)$ and any element of $\Bbb R^2$] to an element of $\Bbb R^4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  The image of the linear transformation represented by a matrix is always the span of the columns.

In this case,  $T\begin {pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=x\begin {pmatrix}1\\2\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}+y\begin {pmatrix}1\\1\\-3\\-3\end{pmatrix}\,,\forall \begin {pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: OK that makes sense in that every vector in $R^4$ can be created by the span of those 2 vectors (x,y).  But then how do you compute the basis vectors for $R^4$ do you transpose matrix A and then RREF?

Comment: Those two vectors $T\begin {pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}1\\2\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $T\begin {pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix} = \begin {pmatrix}1\\1\\-3\\-3\end{pmatrix}$ are pretty obviously linearly independent. And they completely obviously span the range. So they are a basis for the range.

Comment: Isn't the range of $R^4$ bounded by the equations u3 = 2x - 3y and u4 = x - 3y based on the basis vectors described above?  Further, is it not customary to write the range of $R^4$ in terms of its coordinate points (u1,u2,u3,u4)?

Comment: There are, I guess,  a couple ways to write it.   Just as the set of all linear combinations of the columns is one.  Equivalently, $\{\begin {pmatrix}x+y\\2x+y\\2x-3y\\x-3y\end{pmatrix}: x,y\in\Bbb R\}$ would be a slightly different way.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Calculate $T(e_1),T(e_2)$. These two vectors span the image of $T$. If two vectors are independent, then they form a basis of $Im(T)$. If not, then find linearly independent vectors from $T(e_1),T(e_2)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. The general hint is fine (even though not everybody may know what you mean by $e_1$ and $e_2$), but you might want to rethink the last two sentences. Also: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).